# How to wait for a browser to finish redirecting before continuing a test

Tags: c#, selenium

Some of my selenium tests browse a URL that redirects 1 or more times until landing on the right page.
2 problems with this:

- I need a way to determine that the browser stopped redirecting
- I need my test execution to wait until the browser stopped redirecting

Not every redirect takes the same time, so I want to be able to set some boundaries so I can fine tune every test case by case.

Comment: Do you know the expected end URL? Because that's easy. I assume you don't know what the final URL will be?

Comment: In my specific case, I need to check if a list of url's redirects to a login page or not. But that gives me some false positives because my test somtimes starts to compare the browser url against the expected url before redirecting is finished. Some pages redirect up to 2 times, so I need a mechanism that waits until the redirecting is completely done and the final page completely loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a conditional [explicit wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait) seems to do the trick. The `WebDriverWait` object supports a time out and polling interval, so I created a method that will poll the browser for it's URL and if it stays the same for a certain amount of time, assume the browser finished redirecting.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This method continues code execution when the browser url hasn't changed for a given period of time.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pollingInterval">The given period of time.</param>
    /// <param name="timeOut">The period of time to wait untill throwing a exception.</param>
    public void WaitUntilRedirected(TimeSpan pollingInterval, TimeSpan timeOut)
    {
        string url = "";
        bool canContinue = true;

        var wait = Wait;
        wait.Timeout = timeOut;
        wait.PollingInterval = pollingInterval;

        wait.Until(Browser =>
        {
            if (Browser.Url != url)
            {
                url = Browser.Url;
            }
            else
            {
                canContinue = false;
            }

            return canContinue == false;
        });
    }
```

The way I coded this function, it will at least poll the browser 2 times, so tests might take longer to finish depending on what values I provide for the polling interval and timeout.

Comment: This feels like a partial answer. Most concerned about the flake (or false positive) cases where it take a page 2-5 seconds to execute their redirect. Not sure how plausible this is for the OP, but it could easily be on the real life web.

Comment: Hi @DMart, the method has parameters for polling interval and time out. This method can be implemented in such way that you can define the time out and polling interval for each separate page. So if you have one specific test where one specific page takes longer to load, you just need to pass a bigger timespan to address this. I actually implemented this as such in my project and it seems to work just fine.